# Copy TextBox to clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I try to copy all the textbox in the clipboard (when I do a left click on the textbox). I get an error: *User-defined type not defined*. The code:

```
Sub TextBox1_Click()
Dim DataObject As DataObject
          Set DataObject = New DataObject
          DataObject.SetText Me.TextBox1.Text
          DataObject.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Any idea?

Comment: **You canNOT name a variable by any used name like Types, Built-In functions, ...**
So change `Dim DataObject As DataObject` to `Dim AnyThingElseYouWant As DataObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First : you canNOT name a variable by any used name like Types, Built-In functions, ...** 
So change `Dim DataObject As DataObject` to `Dim AnyThingElseYouWant As DataObject`

After that, **2 options if you still have an error** :

1. You may need to explicitly reference the DataObject as being from the Forms library like 
    `Dim Clipboard as MSForms.DataObject`
2. You are missing a reference :

If `MSForms` is not listed in the References list, go to add a reference and then hit the "Browse..." button to look for the file yourself.

`MSForms` is in a file called `FM20.dll` (at least for version 2.0; other versions would be numbered accordingly) which is probably in your Windows\System32 folder.

If you can't find the file, it may have somehow gotten erased and you may need to reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify it as a MSForms.DataObject:

```
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.SetText Me.TextBox1.Text
clipboard.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: you may need to add the msforms reference also, adding a userform should do it, if not there already.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I still have the same error (the line highlighted in yellow for debug is : Sub TextBox1_Click()).

Comment: Is it a Userform? if so i think Its textbox enter or mousedown